# Website not loading after upgraded my GCP

Tags: web, google-cloud-platform, hosting

I got a notification that my trial is running out and I've upgraded my account. Now my website that I'm hosting on GCP is not loading and I have no clue what to do?

Would love your guidance please and thank you!

Comment: Check whether your ip address has changed or not. If you do not reserve a static ip, your VM will be prone to ip address changes.

Comment: Not sure how to check that? And did you mean my site address?

Comment: Which Google Cloud service are you using? The first step is to learn the basics of that service. Google has good videos on YouTube plus numerous tutorials. Start by reading this guide. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Apparently I'm a dumb lol. So when my account expired the VM stopped, I just went in and turned it back on, now my site is LIVE again! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you were facing the [end of free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end). This is the end of the [Free program](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) of 90-days period or free 300$ budget in order to learn Google Cloud Platform.

Important to be aware of the 3rd bullet of the End of Free Trial section:

> Any data you stored in Compute Engine is marked for deletion and might be lost. Learn more about data deletion on Google Cloud.

Taking last parapragh into account, we should [upgrade to a paid Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade) in order to prevent this deletion to happen.

> When you upgrade, the following conditions apply:
>
> - If you upgrade before the trial is over: Any remaining, unexpired    Free Trial credits remain in your Cloud Billing account. You can
>   continue to use the resources you created during the Free Trial
>   without interruption.
>   For resources you use in excess of what's covered by any remaining    credit, your form of payment on file is charged (credit
>   card or bank    account).
> - If you upgrade within 30 days of the end of the trial: Your resources    are marked for deletion, but you might be able to recover
>   them. Learn    more about data deletion on Google Cloud.
> - If you upgrade more than 30 days after the end of the trial, your    Free Trial resources are lost.

Please have a look at [Data Deletion](https://cloud.google.com/security/deletion#deletion_timeline) in order to learn more about this deletion process.